# Replace list of items on text

Tags: python

How do I iterate through list_of_items and replace each item from the list like this

```
for item in list_of_items:
    text.replace(item, ' ' + item)
```

I just don't know how to save the resulting text, so that it would contain all the relevant changes if any.

```
list_of_items = ['PN', 'DESCRIPTION', 'LOCATION', 'CONDITION',
             'RECEIVER#', 'UOM', 'EXP DATE', 'PO', 'CERT SOURCE',
             'REC.DATE', 'MFG', 'BATCH#', 'DOM', 'REMARK', 'LOT#',
             'TAGGED BY', 'Qty', 'NOTES'] 

text = '''
PN: tst SN: 123123
DESCRIPTION: PART
LOCATION: 111 CONDITION: FN
RECEIVER#: 9UOM: EA
EXP DATE: 13.04.2022 PO: P101
CERT SOURCE: wef
REC.DATE:18.04.2022 MFG: efwfe
BATCH# : 1 DOM: 13.04.2022
REMARK: LOT# : 1
TAGGED BY: 
'''
```

Comment: What is the desired final text? Are you just trying to add a space before each of the items in `list_of_items` that appear within `text`?

Comment: `.replace(...)` _returns_ a string with replaced text. It does not update the calling object in place. You would want something like `text = text.replace(...)` if you wanted to update the `text` in place.

Comment: Let's say the `RECEIVER#` is `9UPN: EA`. Your replace code would make it `9U PN:EA` which probably isn't your intention?

Comment: I think you're asking an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the replacement is working as intended and you just want to "save" the new text, simply reassign the new value back to the `text` variable

```
list_of_items = ['PN', 'DESCRIPTION', 'LOCATION', 'CONDITION',
             'RECEIVER#', 'UOM', 'EXP DATE', 'PO', 'CERT SOURCE',
             'REC.DATE', 'MFG', 'BATCH#', 'DOM', 'REMARK', 'LOT#',
             'TAGGED BY', 'Qty', 'NOTES'] 

text = '''
PN: tst SN: 123123
DESCRIPTION: PART
LOCATION: 111 CONDITION: FN
RECEIVER#: 9UOM: EA
EXP DATE: 13.04.2022 PO: P101
CERT SOURCE: wef
REC.DATE:18.04.2022 MFG: efwfe
BATCH# : 1 DOM: 13.04.2022
REMARK: LOT# : 1
TAGGED BY: 
'''

for item in list_of_items:
   text = text.replace(item, ' ' + item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. You need to store the replaced value each time

```
for item in list_of_items:
    text = text.replace(item, ' ' + item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_items = ['PN', 'DESCRIPTION', 'LOCATION', 'CONDITION',
             'RECEIVER#', 'UOM', 'EXP DATE', 'PO', 'CERT SOURCE',
             'REC.DATE', 'MFG', 'BATCH#', 'DOM', 'REMARK', 'LOT#',
             'TAGGED BY', 'Qty', 'NOTES'] 

text = '''
PN: tst SN: 123123
DESCRIPTION: PART
LOCATION: 111 CONDITION: FN
RECEIVER#: 9UOM: EA
EXP DATE: 13.04.2022 PO: P101
CERT SOURCE: wef
REC.DATE:18.04.2022 MFG: efwfe
BATCH# : 1 DOM: 13.04.2022
REMARK: LOT# : 1
TAGGED BY: 
'''
mapper = {e[:e.index(':')]: e[e.index(':')+2:] for e in text.split('\n')[1:-1]}
print([mapper[e] if e in mapper else e for e in list_of_items])
```

prints

```
['tst SN: 123123',
 'PART',
 '111 CONDITION: FN',
 'CONDITION',
 '9UOM: EA',
 'UOM',
 '13.04.2022 PO: P101',
 'PO',
 'wef',
 '8.04.2022 MFG: efwfe',
 'MFG',
 'BATCH#',
 'DOM',
 'LOT# : 1',
 'LOT#',
 '',
 'Qty',
 'NOTES']
```